# Reverse CSS transition on uncheck

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm having a problem reversing a transform when an input is unchecked. As it currently stands the transition doesn't fire it just instantly reverts back to the pre-checked state. I've tried using :not(:checked) but that doesn't seem to be working either.

You can see what I mean here:

```
 .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

  .toggle:checked ~ .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

  .toggle:not(:checked) ~ .overlay {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
```

Here is a pen where you can see the issue - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VarVyP. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

**Edit**
I should have been clearer that the transition that is not reversing is the overlay opacity transition not the drawer push in transition. Unchecking the input moves the drawer back fine but the overlay just instantly reverts to pre-checked state without a transition.

Comment: Your codepen seems to be working fine. Both forward and backword transition, in Chrome. Which browser are you checking in? Or did I not understand your question properly?

Comment: Working fine in firefox also

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't very clear, have updated question with edit - its the overlay transition that isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to define the width and height, as well as z-index in the initial overlay class. It looks like the overlay label is 0,0 in size when closed, and then 100%,100% when open. Telling it to be full size when it's closed is the solution from the looks of it (tested on Chrome)

EDIT: Also, on the .overlay layer, set pointer-events to none. This way, it's only activated on clicking the toggle button.

```
.overlay {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; }

.toggle:checked ~ .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; }

.toggle:not(:checked) ~ .overlay {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reYQQN

Comment: Great! You got it. I was focusing on there being some sort of incorrect use by me of the pseudo but it was a width/height on the overlay issue! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: As an addendum to anyone with same issue I have added pointer-events:all; to .toggle:checked ~ .overlay so that the user can still click anywhere on the screen to reverse back the pre-checked state.